# PDE with `Min` in the definition

Tags: differential-equations

I was trying to come up a some numerical solution to the following PDE system, but it failed for a good reason. Is there a way that we can get around it?

```
r = 0.1; σ = 0.2; K = 40; n = 20; T = 1; q = 0.05;
sol2 = NDSolve[{Min[-D[c[S, t], t] - 
      1/2 σ^2 S^2 D[c[S, t], {S, 2}] - 
      D[c[S, t], S] (r - q) S + r c[S, t], c[S, t] - (S - K)] == 0,

   c[0, t] == 0, 
   c[S, T] == (S - K) Boole[S > K],
   c[3 K, t] == 3 K - K E^(-r (T - t))


   }, c, {t, 0, T}, {S, 0, 120}

  ]
```

Comment: Side issue: [Avoid capital single-letter variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395). For instance, `K` is used as a dummy variable in solutions expressed in terms of sums and integrals.  Probably not an issue here, but it's a good habit.

Comment: I feel there should be some form of a trapezoidal differentiation to avoid calculating the derivative directly.

Comment: Have you seen the tutorial on the [Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)?  I doubt `NDSolve` can handle this directly as a PDE, but maybe it could with a system of ODEs, for which more robust discontinuity processing is available.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think the `Min` will still not allow it.

Comment: I'm afraid even if there's no `Min`, `NDSolve` will have trouble in solving the problem, because part of the equation is inverse problem for parabolic equation (the i.c. is given at `T`, while you're solving the equation from `T` to `0`), which is a well-known [ill-posed problem](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjthqrF-_XTAhVL1oMKHTNUAtYQFggxMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.nsc.ru%2FLBRT%2Fu2%2FSurvey%2520paper.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE9xMzVUg5GG8s_rsVxnXOL9dGyDQ&sig2=lIK4tSznE8Spr3str1nBMw).